# Can't access an object's methods

Tags: java

I'm very new to Java and might not see sth obvious, but here's my problem:

For some reason I cannot access the methods of my class `MenuItem`:

```
public class MenuItem {
    String name;
    double price;

    public MenuItem (String name, double price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return this.name + "\t" + this.price;
    }
}
```

In the following code snippet my IDE underlines the method `getName()` red and says:

> "cannot find symbol"

This is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   ArrayList<Object> menuItems = new ArrayList<Object>();

   menuItems.add(new MenuItem("Pizza", 2.22));

   System.out.println(menuItems.get(0).getName());
}
```

I compared my code with code of other's and cannot find any difference.

Somehow the `toString()` method works perfectly fine. It returns `this.name + "\t" + this.price;` and not `filechallenge.MenuItem@15db9742` which it does when I delete the method.

Does anybody have an idea? I really don't get it...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does a "Cannot find symbol" compilation error mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-compilation-error-mean)

Comment: What type do you think `menuItems.get(0)` is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ArrayList<Object> menuItems ;
```

is typed to hold references of `Object`. It doesn't know what you add at Runtime.

Change it to specific type

```
List<MenuItem> menuItems = new ArrayList<MenuItem>();
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped. So, I assume it is not possible for an ArrayList to hold objects of different classes?

Comment: It is possible. You can have something like `<? extends SomeBaseClass>`. Read more about [generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was this line: `ArrayList<Object> menuItems = new ArrayList<Object>();`. You're trying to call `getName()` on an `Object`, not a `MenuItem`.

```
import java.util.*;

public class MenuItem {
  String name;
  double price;

  public MenuItem (String name, double price) {
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return this.name;
  }

  public String toString() {
    return this.name + "\t" + this.price;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
     ArrayList<MenuItem> menuItems = new ArrayList<MenuItem>();

     menuItems.add(new MenuItem("Pizza", 2.22));
     //System.out.println(menuItems);
     System.out.println(menuItems.get(0).getName());
  }
}
```

Or if you want to keep the list full of `Object`s, you can explicitly cast the `Object` to `MenuItem` when you pull the item out like below:

```
import java.util.*;

public class MenuItem {
  String name;
  double price;

  public MenuItem (String name, double price) {
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return this.name;
  }

  public String toString() {
    return this.name + "\t" + this.price;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
     ArrayList<Object> menuItems = new ArrayList<Object>();

     menuItems.add(new MenuItem("Pizza", 2.22));
     //System.out.println(menuItems);
     MenuItem mi = (MenuItem) menuItems.get(0);
     System.out.println(mi.getName());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this statement

```
System.out.println(((MenuItem)menuItems.get(0)).getName());
```

(or)

```
ArrayList<MenuItem> MenuItems = new ArrayList<MenuItem>();
menuItems.add(new MenuItem("Pizza", 2.22));
System.out.println(menuItems.get(0).getName());
```

You need to typecast it properly before calling the method. Hope this will help u